# The distributions of incomes in two cities follow the two Pareto type pdfs. Find P(X<Y)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The distributions of incomes in two cities follow the two Pareto type pdfs

$$f(x)= \frac{2}{x^3}, 1 < x < \infty.$$

$$g(y) = \frac{3}{y^4}, 1<y<\infty.$$

Here one unit represents ${$20,000}$. One person with income is selected at random from each city. Let X and Y be their respective incomes. Compute $P(X<Y)$.

It's confusing me because of $P(X<Y)$

I think we can make an assumption that X and Y are statistically independent?

Then

$$f(x,y) = f(x)f(y) = \frac{6}{x^3y^4}$$

But I still don't see how we compute $P(X<Y)$?

Maybe use

$$E[X-Y] = E[X] - E[Y]?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the part of the plane where $x\lt y$. Then our probability is
$$\iint_C f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy,$$
where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$. So the region of integration is the region above the line $y=x$. And yes, we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Express as an iterated integral. It is convenient to integrate first with respect to $y$. Our probability is 
$$\int_{x=1}^\infty\left( \int_{y=x}^\infty \frac{6}{x^3 y^4}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$